# Rails 7 - validate to 1 month period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 application I've got two param filters - `from_date` and `to_date`. Inside of my controller I want to validate max date range to be set as 1 month. So when from_date and to_date period will be bigger I want to `redirect_to root_path`.

How to count this period?

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to implement a validation in the model and show an error when the range is too long while creation or update? Or do you want to check the range size in the controller and redirect the user?

Comment: I'm assuming `from_date` and `to_date` are of type `String`? If so, you could convert them from `String` to `Date` (with `.to_date` for example) then subtract one date from the other and convert that result to an `Integer` to count the number of days between both dates (with `.to_i` for example).

So it may look like this in the end:
`(params[:to_date].to_date - params[:from_date].to_date).to_i`

Comment: @spickermann second approach is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @benj-p I see where you're going - 1 month is not always the same number of days.

Comment: Oh yes that's right! Then the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76102321/11330290) from @spickermann should work

Answer (score 1):

In the controller method, I would call a method to check if range size is valid:

```
redirect_to(root_path) unless date_range_okay?
```

And the method to check the range size could look like this:

```
private 

def date_range_okay?
  from_date = params[:from_date].to_date
  to_date   = params[:to_date].to_date

  to_date < (from_date >> 1)
end
```

See [`Date#>>`](https://rubyapi.org/o/date#method-i-3E-3E) that returns a date `n` months later (with `n` being `1` in this case) and it takes the different length of months into account.

You might want to extend the method to be able to handle `nil` values or invalid dates.